# How to create a multiple values for a single key using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

As we all know local storage is a key value pair. Trying to create a multiple values to a single key. But unable to get how to pass the multiple values for a single key.

Here it is simple what have created.

```
var value = "aa"
localStorage.setItem("testKey", value);
var test = localStorage.getItem("testKey");
alert(test);
```

Now here what want to achieve is `testKey` should have `aa, bb and cc` values.

If it is possible can anyone please help me out with a sample.

Note:

> Will localStorage values work for native app.

Comment: you can split the saved value into an array using a non-conflicting char. this is easy since localStorage is unicode. it saves a lot of space when storing thousands of short items this way compared to JSON's 3char-per-string item overhead

Comment: @dandavis: Is the same thing what Azmisov has given in the answer

Answer (score 13):

This is not possible with localstorage. However, you can store a JSON string as the value for the key, and with a little post-processing, you can extract your three variables:

```
var value = ["aa","bb","cc"]
localStorage.setItem("testKey", JSON.stringify(value));
var test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testKey"));
alert(test);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Have doubt which already mention in the question. Does native app also store this localstorage value

Comment: As far as I know, it will work. You just have to make sure the native app supports the JSON methods.

Answer (score 4):

A single key can only have a single string value in localStorage. You can have multiple keys with different names, or you can do some encoding of the values. For example, you could put all your values in an Array, then encode it using JSON.stringify() and store the result in localStorage. When you read the data back, you can use JSON.parse() to turn it back into an Array.

Comment: can't I store an array or object in local storage?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do that, using json arrays for example you want to store this array with two items

```
      var items =    {
            "1": {
            "id": 7606606,
            "item_id": "2",
            "row": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "amount": 0,
                    "plan": 1
                    }
                  },
             "2": {
            "id": 7606623,
            "item_id": "3",
            "row": {
                    "id": "3",
                    "amount": 0,
                    "plan": 1
                    }
                  }
           }
```

Convert that to json then store in local storage like this

```
             localStorage.setItem('myItems', JSON.stringify(items));
```

then you retrieve the same way

```
             var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItems'));
```

then you can use foreach to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

```
        <form>
    <label>Mortgage Amount</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount">
    <label>Interest Rate % </label>
    <input type="text" id="interest">
    <label>Mortgage Period (Years)</label>
    <input type="text" id="period">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn">
    <input type="button" value="GetLocalStorage" id="localbtn">
</form>
           <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn").click(function () {

        var principal = $("#amount").val();
        var interest = $("#interest").val();
        var years = $("#period").val();
        var item = [];
       item.push(principal,interest,years);
       localStorage.item += JSON.stringify({ "principalAmount": principal, "interestAmount": interest, "Period": years });


    });
```

Comment: You can store multiple values in local storage with single key.Just you have to append after you push values into an array. i-e.localStorage.item+=