# How to generate one object key with an array of stored values from multiple on click events using localstorage and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm new to coding, and I need to display past search values from an input field using localstorage. The only way I can think of is by using one object key with an array of stored values from an on click event. Problem is, I can only get one position to appear as a value, with each value generated replacing the last. I've tried for loops and can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I have so far:

```
$('.search-city').on('click', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    var textArr = [];
    var text = $(".form-control").val();
    textArr.push(text);
    localStorage.setItem("value1", textArr);  
});

$('.search-city').on('click', function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();
var search = localStorage.getItem("value1")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a multiple values for a single key using local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544861/how-to-create-a-multiple-values-for-a-single-key-using-local-storage)

Comment: Not really. This is one of the comments:

"You can store multiple values in local storage with single key.Just you have to append after you push values into an array. i-e.localStorage.item+="

I don't understand what is meant by this. It also doesn't address the fact that I need to add values one at a time via user input.

Comment: Make your value an array, call JSON.stringify(myarray), store that in local storage. When you pull it out, call JSON.parse and pass in the string value, now you have an array again a and can add remove. Rise. Repeat.

Comment: @WesleySmith 

"When you pull it out, call JSON.parse and pass in the string value, now you have an array again a and can add remove. Rise. Repeat."

I'm not sure what you mean by pass in the string value is. I don't know what the value is going to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
$('.search-city').on('click', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the value from local storage
    var localValue = localStorage.getItem('value1');

    // if we had a value, parse it back to an array, if we dont, create an empty array
    var textArr = localValue ? JSON.parse(localValue) : [];

    // get the text from the search input, dont use "form-control"
    // you're likely to have several of those on the page
    // give the element a custom class like "search-input" and use that (id would be even better)
    var text = $('.search-input').val();

    // add the text to the array
    text = trim(text);
    if (text) {
        textArr.push(text);
    }

    // enforce a size limit here by removing the 0 index item if the count has grown too large
    var maxAllowed = 10;
    while (textArr.length > maxAllowed) {
         textArr.shift();
    }

    // localstorage can only hold simple strings so we'll JSON stringify our object and store that 
    localValue = JSON.stringify(textArr);
    localStorage.setItem("value1", localValue);  
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful comments as well.